# Finding Accuracy of a Clustering Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, cluster-analysis

How to find the accuracy of a clustering algorithm given the true clustering and predicted clustering of the algorithm?

I searched the web but couldn't find any useful source. I know how to compute accuracy of classification algorithm.

Comment: What's any different then? You count how often you clustered the data into the right cluster, divided by the count of all items.

Comment: This question would be better answered on http://stats.stackexchange.com. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There exist a number of methods, and some of them are discussed on the [Wikipedia page "Cluster analysis", section "External evaluation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#External_evaluation).

Pair-counting based indexes (F-Measure, Rand, etc.) seem to be the most popular. They are quite easy to compute; actually easier than the some of the set matching measures (hungarian algorithm to find the optimal 1:1 alignment is in `O(n^3)`, while all the pair counting measures can be computed in a linear pass over the intersection matrix, so in `O(n^2)`. (`n` is the number of clusters.)

You can find a novel visual experiment (but in my experience it is not that useful on real data, more for understanding the differences of two algorithms on 2d toy data) based on the pair counting measures (along with an implementation of a dozen of external measures) in:

> Achtert, Elke, et al. "Evaluation of Clusterings--Metrics and Visual Support." Data Engineering (ICDE), 2012 IEEE 28th International Conference on. IEEE, 2012.

Note that there is a big issue with comparing a new clustering to "known" clusterings:

By doing so, you actually *punish* novel solutions.

But when using cluster analysis, you want a *novel* solution. If it were just the labels you already had, you could just *use* the labels you already have. In fact, a good clustering result will *diverge* from the known solution, and offer an alternate view on the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use ROC curve for analysis of clustering quality, if of course your clustering is supervised.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic

Comment: Uhm, ROC is designed for binary problems. What if there is more than two clusters? Define "true positive rate", please.

Comment: Usually, there are more than two clusters, in which case the ROC does not work.

Comment: The problem can be transformed in to a binary classification problem, as discussed in (Manning et al., 2008), below:
"...a series of decisions, one for each of the N(N-1)/2 pairs of documents in the collection. We want to assign two documents to the same cluster if and only if they are similar. A true positive (TP) decision assigns two similar documents to the same cluster..."
Christopher D. Manning, Prabhakar Raghavan and Hinrich Schütze, Introduction to Information Retrieval, Cambridge University Press. 2008.
http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html